# In Firebase's Realtime Database, how can I pass my own arguments to an event listener's callback?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is pseudo-code for the way you write a listener for a Realtime Database event.

```js
function callbackA(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}

route.on('value', callbackA);
```

Now imagine I want to pass some arguments to callbackA so that callbackA might look like this:

```js
function callbackA(snapshot, myParam1, myParam2) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  console.log(myParam1);
  console.log(myParam2);
}
```

How can I do this (without ruining the first arg that firebase automatically provides for us)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the arguments that the Firebase SDK passes to the callback function.  It will always attempt to pass exactly one argument: the snapshot.

Instead, you could simply provide the values as variables within the scope of the callback, and access them directly.

```
const myParam1 = ...
const myParam2 = ...

function callbackA(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  console.log(myParam1)
  console.log(myParam2)
}
```

Or you can use [function currying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/807126) to create a new function to pass as the callback.  It might go something like this (this untested code - use your best judgement here):

```
function callbackA(myParam1, myParam2) {
    return function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
}

const callbackB = callbackA("value-for-myparam1", "value-for-myparam2")
route.on('value', callbackB);
```

You will obviously need to know the values for the params before you call the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this isn't possible @DougStevenson